# How to Kill a PHP process and delete the Uneraseable File?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, php5, ftp

I'm trying to delete a file on the server but the PHP is still busy on it and wont let me delete it... FTP says SORRY cant do:

```
> DELE ml.txt
< 550 ml.txt: Permission denied
> PORT 190,028,4,31,129,100
```

and

```
> SITE CHMOD 777 ml.txt
< 550 ml.txt: Operation not permitted
```

What to do, in order to kill the process or delete the file?

Answer (score 1):

try, ssh => login as root, try renaming the file and then delete it.

Comment: or else you could also try deleting the files by chmod +777

Answer (score 1):

Why not just stop the web server and restart?

If running php directly, simply use top to find the process and kill it.

```
top | grep "php"
```

Find the process id and then

```
kill "processId"
```

or even simpler enough:

```
killall php
```

Answer (score 1):

1. login as normal user on ssh
2. then type in `su -`
3. it will prompt you for the root password, then enter that.
4. one you are in you need to change the owner ship of the file by `chown -r change_with_your_username:change_with_your_usergroup change_with_full_path_to_the_file`
5. then try deleting it through ftp or ssh and it should work.

if the steps above dont work then try this

1. if it is locked as in RCS (revision control system) or SCCS (source code control system) , you (hopefully owner) can unlock it `rcs -u YourFileName` see `man rcs` if it is installed in your system. see `man sccs` to learn how to unlock with sccs. unfortunately i don't know.
2. if your file is in use, you can see it with `fuser -m TheFileName` or the directoryName holding it `fuser` is file user. see `man fuser` to see how to kill the process using your file. i think it is `fuser -km FileName`. better investigate it yourself. If you know which process is using your file you can terminate the process with `kill` command.
3. use `lsattr YourFileName` to see the attributes of your file. it might be set as immutable or undeletable with command `chattr -i filename` or `chattr -u filename` if so you can do the opposite with `chattr +i +u filename` see `man chattr` or `man lsattr` for more detail. `chattr` and `lsattr` come with newer systems. my fedora2 has it. older systems don't

Comment: did it work??? let me know.. :) good luck

Comment: Thanks user!! +1 again this helps. (I donno why my question got downvoted? I dont care. Your answer rocks.)

Comment: thanks sam for the rep. I have upvoted your question because it is perfectly valid and a good question.